# Pending OCUnit tests

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocunit

Is there any way to denote a pending test using OCUnit?  Of course, I could do something like:

`STFail(@"pending test");`

However, it becomes all too easy to see a failed test run and assume that it's my pending test.  I'm looking for some way to signal to myself that "this test still needs to be written", but I'm not ready to do it just yet!  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've used #warning compiler directives for this. That way they show up in Xcode as constant reminders but won't get confused with failing tests.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use Bookmarks in Xcode if you don't want to see failing tests. Support for bookmarks changed quite a bit with Xcode 4.x, but they are still there, or the //FIXME //TODO choices. That's about it.

I do believe it would be great if there were a way to outline what needs to be tested and have the IDE help you check off the items. If you have ever looked at Ken Beck's book *Test-Driven Development*, he espouses using checklists and strikethrough. There are some tools that do that pretty well, that you could even get to work inside xcode.

Xcode needs to get much more serious about TDD!